# strpos issue for creating tags

Tags: tags, strpos

Good evening. 
Im creating a strpos code to take out tags from descriptions. 
Like for an article about hamburgers, im using strpos to show different words as tags if they are in the description.

Issue: If I create one codeline of strpos for eatch possible word im seaching, they will all take the css and show as blank result/tag if the word isnt there.

If I use the code as below, it will only return 1 result and no more. How can I change this to show all results?

public function article_criteria_tags($description){
$a = strtolower($description);

```
if (strpos($a, 'milk') !== false) { return 'milk'; }
if (strpos($a, 'water') !== false) { return 'water'; }
if (strpos($a, 'flour') !== false) { return 'Høyre'; }  
if (strpos($a, 'pastry') !== false) { return 'pastry'; }    
if (strpos($a, 'apple') !== false) { return 'apple'; }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix for this was to separate them all into separat codelines and move the button in the code. Like;
`<?php $a = strtolower($criteria); if (strpos($a, 'milk') !== false) { ?> <button class="button-tag"> <?php echo  'milk'; }?> </button>`